# OSPF For Routed Access

Tags: cisco, ospf

I have a Telecommunications provider installing a router running OSPF v3 in area 0, I want to integrate my switches with it to exchange routes.

Seems straightforward however I will be using OSPF for Routed access which I'm not familiar with.

Does anyone know if the below will work?

```
router ospf 1
 network 1.1.1.0 0.0.0.255 area 0 #Subnet to Router
 network 2.2.2.0 0.0.0.255 area 0 #My Network to advertise
!
```

Comment: Can't tell for sure without more information.  Do you have a diagram of some sort?  What kind of switch(es) do you have?  Did you really mean OSPFv3 and not v2?  V3 uses IPv6 addressing.

Comment: Your example shows OSPFv2, not OSPFv3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"OSPF for Routed Access" is a Cisco licensing term. It is a normal OSPF implementation, but it's limited by licensing to 1 instance and 200 learned routes (see [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-4500-series-switches/product_bulletin_c25-553133.html)). If you want to run more instances or learn more routes, you need to upgrade to another license (from IP Base to IP Sevices in general).

Your config should work, as long as it is OSPF v2 (not v3) and you're not using authentication (which you should consider in my opinion).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, it is indeed OSPF v2 (IPv4 network). Use of authentication is a great suggestion .